# VScode настройка автозаполнения jsx

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

При работе с файлами .html vscode позволяет начать писать class  и при нажатии таб получить такой результат class="" , но при работе с jsx результат после таб  className, а хотелось получить className="", тоже самое касательно других атрибутов. Есть ли возможность это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно настроить свои кастомные сниппеты

1. Setting -> User Snippets

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Далее в появившемся окне выбираете language mode на который будет распространятся действия ваших сниппетов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Создаем собственный сниппет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример для вашего случая:

```
"ClassName React": {
    "prefix": "cls",
    "body": "className=\"$1\""
}
```

`ClassName React` - название сниппета (ни на что не влияет)

`prefix` - комбинация после которой нужно будет нажать `Tab`

`body` - то что будет отображаться в итоге

`$1` - место где будет стоять курсор

P.S. еще там экранированы двойный кавычки обратными слэшами

Answer (score 0):

Какой язык у вас выбран в настройках? Javacript React или просто Javascript?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: пробовал оба варианта

Comment: странно, у меня Javacript React и вроде как больше ничего не устанавливал, и `className` предлагает

Comment: className и мне предлагает хотелось бы получить результат className=""  как это происходит в хтмл